# Vibration volume for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin Forms app for Android. The app has two buttons. If you click on them then they should have different vibration volume. Please do not confuse with vibration time in seconds. It's about vibration intensity. My question has Xamarin Forms this possibility ? 
Thank you

Comment: Look at Xamarin.Essentials, it has a `Vibration` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/vibrate?tabs=android)

Comment: Currently Xamarin.Essentials does not support the extended haptic features on Android API level 26+ (nor the iOS haptic engine), you would need to use a DS to access those native features (if an enhanced haptics even exists on the Android device as only the original vibrator is required to be supported, ie. time|pattern) :  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect

Comment: Xamarin.Essentials' Vibrate class does not have volume, it only has duration. I think we should stick to native APIs by the help of DependencyService.